# The Jewish View on a Person's Physical Appearance?

Tags: tanach, chazal

In my experience Judaism doesn’t place any importance at all in a persons appearance, wether they are attractive or not. Does anywhere in TaNaCh or Chazal even discuss this topic? (That appearance isn’t important, or so & so was particularly handsome or ugly, or that people shouldn’t be judged based on looks)

Comment: I would disagree with your assumption. The Torah consistently says how beautiful Sarah, Rachel and Rivka were. Same thing regarding Joseph, Sha'ul and David. Please further define what you mean by "not important".

Comment: Also there is a relevant answer here : https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40305/is-it-better-to-be-ugly-or-beautiful

Comment: I don’t mean to be dismissive, I’m genuinely curious: Does *any* religion place any importance...? It’s a fact of life; attractive appearance (as subjective as it may be) is a natural want in a couple’s marital life. Sure you can pluck quotes from any corpus (take [Bavli Ket. 59b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.59b.9?with=Modern%20Commentary&lang=bi) for example) and read into whatever you want but a clear ideology can emerge only from a thorough [and systematic] knowledge of any religion’s core texts.